# IIS 10.5 does not Transfer-Encoding Chunked in HTTP Requests (Upload Operations)

Tags: asp.net-web-api, .net-framework-version, iis-10, http-1.1

We have an ASP.NET WEBAPI application running on IIS 10.5 where we have offered a upload file API.
Since, we expect large files above 1 GB or so, we are performing some tests chunked transfer encoding.
It is observed that IIS 10.5 does not accept requests having transfer encoding set to Chunked.

On the .NET Framework side, we do have an option to use "bufferless" inputstream to avoid buffering and with this, we can avoid buffering on the receiving side but this is not same as chunked encoding.

API consumer applications send requests having chunked transfer encoding set and these requests are failing. Though, it is possible to ask consumer applications not to send this header, this can create a potential issue on the consumer side as all content gets buffered on the client side resulting in memory issue and it can eventually run out of memory.

As per HTTP 1.1, chunked encoding should be supported on both sender and receiver side. There is an argument in the forums that chunked encoding only applies to "Response" and not "Request".  But it seems logical to support this on both side and HTTP 1.1 spec seems to talking about both ends though it is not explicitly mentioned.

For example, Apache HTTP Clients do support chunked encoding during the file uploads as well.

Is there a way to enable chunked encoding support? or is any reason why it is not supported in IIS 10.5 ? Any help / thoughts in this is really appreciated.

Comment: Hi, has the problem been solved? If you think my reply is helpful to you, you can mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The AspEnableChunkedEncoding in IIS can enable chunked encoding:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/iis/6.0-sdk/ms526005(v=vs.90)

There are similar issue in this [blog](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/iis-support-blog/enabling-8220-transfer-encoding-chunked-8221-in-the-response/ba-p/287869).